# How to validate a JSON 2D Array using Rest Assured?

Tags: java, json, rest, api, rest-assured

Here is the question.

**Part 1:**

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "address": "765 the the",
      "number": "3277772345",
    },
    {
      "name": "Lee",
      "address": "456 no where",
       "number": "7189875432",
    },  
  ]
}
```

I want to validate the number field i.e. if the number is `"7189875432"`. The JSON Path to `"7189875432"` is: `people[1]. number` (which is inside a JSON Array).

To do this, I did the fellowing:

```
List<String> value=
given()
.when()
.get("/person")
.then()
.extract()
.path("people.findAll{it.number=='7189875432}. number");
 If (value.isEmpty)
            assert.fail();
```

This test will pass.
Basically, if the value is there it will return a list of that value. This I understand. But now let's says I have a JSON such as:

**Part 2**

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "address": "765 the the",
      "phoneno": [
        {
          "number": "3277772345",

        },
        {
          "number": "654787654",

        },

      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Lee",
      "address": "456 no where",
      "phoneno": [
        {
          "number": "7189875432",

        },
        {
          "number": "8976542234",

        },
        {
          "number": "987654321",

        },

      ]
    },

  ]
}
```

Now I want to validate if the phone number `"987654321"` is in the JSON. The JSON Path: `people[1].phoneno[2].number`

```
List<String> value=
given()
.when()
.get("/person")
.then()
.extract()
.path("people.phoneno.findAll{it.number=='987654321'}. number");
 If (value.isEmpty)
            assert.fail();
```

This test will fail because it will return an empty string.

If I hard code the path like:

```
.path("people[1].phoneno.findAll{it.number=='987654321'}. number");
 If (value.isEmpty)
            assert.fail(); // this test will pass
```

Also if I so do something like this

```
 .path("people.phoneno. number");
I would get a list such as [["987654321", "3277772345", "7189875432", "8976542234"]]
```

with a list of all number in the JSON.

So my question is how can we validate a JSON path that has an array inside another array? I do not want to hardcode anything.

Note: The only information available is the number i.e `"987654321"`

Answer (score 1):

You can always write your own custom matcher:

```
private static Matcher<List<List<String>>> containsItem(String item) {
    return new TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher<List<List<String>>>() {
      @Override
      protected boolean matchesSafely(List<List<String>> items, Description mismatchDescription) {
        return items.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(toList()).contains(item);
      }

      @Override
      public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText(
            String.format("(a two-dimensional collection containing \"%s\")", item));
      }
    };
  }
```

And then use this matcher:

```
given()
.when()
.get("/person")
.then()
.body("people.phoneno.number", containsItem("987654321"));
```

To make this matcher even more reusable, make input type generic:
`private static <T> Matcher<List<List<T>>> containsItem(T item) {...}`